# Why href and <a> tag not working using sublime 3?

Tags: html, sublimetext3, href

I'm literally just starting to learn how to use HTML to learn how to build a website with the end goal of working out how to implement google analytics tags to get a better understanding of how things work in my 9-5 job.

HTML seems easy enough so far however when I'm using the "< a >" or href tags there doesn't seem to be anything appearing when opening the file in chrome.

I've been using sublime 3 as a text editor and it did pop up about purchasing the software or something after I'd written a few lines of html and tried to save it (sorry I didn't fully read the message before closing it).  So I'm not sure if it's something to do with sublime 3 or my coding.  It's probably something very simple and stupid I've done so any help would be appreciated.

HTML code below:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>MY WEBPAGE!</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Yo! Sup!</h1>   

    <h2>you can use header tags to create big heads in size 1-6</h2>

        <br> <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dGpZEuXoFWw/hqdefault.jpg">

    <br>  <br> You need to use br tag to create a new line

        <p>You can write in <strong>bold</strong>
            <br> You can also write in <em>italics</em>
            <br> Can you do <em><strong>both?</strong></em>
        </p>

    <p>You don't always have to use double br tags to start a new paragraph you can use the p tag, the good thing about p tag is it creates a space either side of the paragraph
    </p>

    What about underline?

    <br> <br> You can use the a tag to link to another site <a google.com></a>

    <br> <br> but you need to add a href in <a href="www.google.co.uk"></a>

    <br> <br> You can also you the img tag to identify an image source 

    <br> <br> you can create an unordered list using the ul and li tags which are used to create lists for drop downs and navigations

    <br> <br> 

    <ul>

        <li> first list item </li>

        <li> second list item </li>

        <li> third list item </li>

    </ul>

    <br> you can create an ordered list (which basically just gives the list numbers) by using the ol tag

    <ol>

        <li> first list item </li>

        <li> second list item </li>

        <li> third list item </li>

    </ol>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you need to put text between the <a></a> tags   <a href="www.google.com">google</a>

Comment: `<a href="https://google.com">google.com</a>`, not `<a google.com></a>`. The tag needs to be told where it's linking to and what text the page should display. This also has nothing to do with the software you used to edit the text, for what it's worth. The message you saw was something Sublime pops up every few saves you remind you that you should buy it if you decide to continue using it. Except for being annoying this has no effect on anything.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need To put some Text inside that a tag! For instance

`<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>`

Comment: ah! excellent! thank you Mika, I knew it'd be something stupid I'd done.